# Hive: Creating a table within a case statement

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to update a table once in a period, however periods are either 4 or 5 weeks long. 
In order to schedule a SQL query to run this process, I have been attempting to use the create table statement as a result of a successful `when` clause.

Is this possible as I am not getting any joy and cannot find anything that states one way or the other.

e.g.

```
select
    case when 1=1 then
        (create table db.case_test_1 as
        select 'Y' as test)
    end as test
```

Comment: No, you can't do some sort of conditional execution in a sql script.  You'll need to look into using shell scripts to do this.

Comment: Your question started off with "I need to update a table", but you are trying to create one. What is your actual requirement. Can you explain in a bit more detail please

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I suspected this but couldn't find anything that specifically confirmed or denied this.